# pandas extract using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column that has numbers in format x.x or x.xx randomly embedded in a string. I can separately extract such numbers using

```
pd[colName].str.extract('(\d\.\d)') or
pd[colName].str.extract('(\d\d\.\d)')
```

And then merging the two results. But how would I combines these two conditions together using some sort of 'or' condition to achieve the same in one go.

Comment: `pd[colName].str.extract('(\d\.\d|\d\d\.\d)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd[colName].str.extract('(\d\.\d{1,2})')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go and report back!

Comment: Thank you, worked well with a trivial edit (hope you dont mind).